# Get filename without the extension with regex

Tags: regex

I need to find a way to obtain a match on a specific file name without the extension.

```
Test App 0.2.1.exe
dsdsad

Test App 0.2.1.dmg
Test App 0.2.1
```

Currently I've tried `^\S+\.(?:dmg)$` but it doesn't match.

So basically I want to get result of:

`Test App 0.2.1` (not with the extension). Just to obtain the name so I can use that name to save in a variable in GitHub Actions. Currently I'm using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/actions-ecosystem-action-regex-match.

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hY7Xfp/1

Comment: Like this? `^(\S.*)\.dmg$` with a capture group? https://regex101.com/r/TYR21D/1

Comment: Or just `(.*)\.dmg$` or even ``(.*)\.dmg``

Comment: Or even more generally `(.*)\.[^.]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
.+(?=\.[a-z0-9]+)
```

The above expression matches the file names for you regardless of their extensions (doesn't match the extension itself) .

and if you want to match file names only with .dmg extension (doesn't match the .dmg itself) , you can try this :

```
.+(?=(\.dmg))
```

Note: If you want to match file names with other extensions, just change the .dmg part in the above expression.

for instance :

```
.+(?=(\.exe)) #Matches file names with .exe extension

.+(?=(\.jpg)) #Matches file names with .jpg extension

.+(?=(\.mp3)) #Matches file names with .mp3 extension

  and so on ...
```

I have a point for you in this link.

[RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/72ot9) | check it out .

I hope this helps :)

Comment: `{1,}` is just a verbose rearticulation of `+`

Comment: You're right  i edited it .